# Adding lines to a python script from a file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

Suppose we have an s3 bucket `test` and a folder `files` within that bucket. In this folder there are two text files: `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

`file1.txt` contains the one line: `a = a+6`

`file2.txt` contains the one line: `a = a*11`

If we have a python file called `test.py` with the following code:

```
a = 2
```

how would er add the lines from `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` so that `test.py` looks like:

```
a = 2
a = a+6
a = a*11
```

Would it be something like the following:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = "test"
key = "files"
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
a = 2
obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I like simplicity. So, I would write a second script that reads and edits the first script as a text file then runs in python (cmd!).

Comment: @AbdurRakib: The point is to read those lines from an s3 bucket.

Comment: Your code sample will retrieve the contents of the object from S3. You would then use Python file-handling commands to write a new file. Or, you could download the files to your local disk using `download_file()` and then read the contents of the files using normal Python file-handling commands.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Is there ever a case where you would recommend putting python code in text files within an s3 bucket and then reading/appending that code to a python script? Maybe if you have a pipeline/glue job that takes a long time to deploy? So you can just rerun the step function/glue job instead of having to redeploy the new code?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Actually might as well read from a .py file in the bucket instead of multiple files.